# Doesn't work check whether the button is pressed

Tags: java, android-studio, action, android-button, ontouchlistener

I try to make a button that only works when you press and hold it: if you press and move your finger away from the button to another area, it will stop working, and if you press to another area and, while holding your finger, point it at the button, it will work. On stackoverflow.com one user responded and wrote onTouchListener:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener () {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if (v.getLeft () <= event.getX () && v.getRight ()> = event.getX () && v.getTop () <= event.getY () && v.getBottom ()> = event. getY ()) {
                   if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                       Log.d ("LOG", "pressed");
                    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                       Log.d ("LOG", "released");
                    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                       Log.d ("LOG", "moving");
               }
               else
               {
                   Log.d ("LOG", "out of area");
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
```

I tried this code, but it did not work: [Code](https://prnt.sc/oh7nvb) [Logs](https://prnt.sc/oh7re6)

By the way, if you do not use this check `if (v.getLeft () <= event.getX () && v.getRight ()> = event.getX () && v.getTop () <= event.getY () && v .getBottom ()> = event.getY ()) {`, the button works, but not as it should (without checking button presses)

Comment: Press and holding it, why don't you use setOnLongClickListener() ?

Comment: onLongClickListener() processes the event and immediately ends it (example: the opening menu when clicked in the text area)